# FSTP instruction in NASM won't write into memory

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Here is the code:

```
section .data
    first_num dd 0
    second_num dd 0
    print_fmt db '%.2lf ', 0
section .bss
    result resb 8
section .text
extern printf, strtol
global main
%macro string_to_number 2
    PUSH rdi
    PUSH rsi
    PUSH rdx
    PUSH rax

    mov rdi, %2
    mov rsi, 0
    mov rdx, 10
    mov rax, 0
    call strtol
    mov [%1], eax

    POP rax
    POP rdx
    POP rsi
    POP rdi
%endmacro
%macro print 0
    PUSH rdi
    PUSH rsi
    PUSH rdx
    PUSH rax

    mov rdi, print_fmt
    mov rsi, [result]
    mov rax, 0
    call printf

    POP rax
    POP rdx
    POP rsi
    POP rdi
%endmacro
main:
    PUSH rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    cmp rdi, 3
    jl .end

    add rsi, 8
    string_to_number first_num, [rsi]
    add rsi, 8
    string_to_number second_num, [rsi]

    fild dword [first_num]
    fsqrt
    fstp qword [result] ; <--THIS
    print

.end:
    POP rbp
    mov rax, 0
    ret
```

The program is not yet finished. I just wanted to print the square root of the first command line argument and test it. I debbuged everything with gdb, and everything works fine until `FSTP` command. At that point the correct root is in `st0`(top of FPU stack), and after `FSTP` command, there is nothing written in result location (it's zero) and `st0` is zero. I don't understand what happens. I tried changing the size of `result`, using `FST` instead of `FSTP` but nothing different happens.

Here is the makefile:

```
test.o: test.asm
    nasm -f elf64 -g -F dwarf test.asm -o test.o
test: test.o
    gcc -o test test.o -no-pie
```

I am compiling this in Linux 64-bit.

Here is copy paste from terminal:

```
linux@DESKTOP-QF0T5NR:/mnt/c/Users/Path$ gdb -q --arg build/zad5 12 13
Reading symbols from build/zad5...done.
(gdb) break 60
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4005ab: file zad5.asm, line 60.
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 2 at 0x400540: file zad5.asm, line 47.
Starting program: /mnt/c/Users/Path/build/zad5 12 13

Temporary breakpoint 2, main () at zad5.asm:47
47              PUSH rbp
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, main () at zad5.asm:60
60              fstp qword [result]
(gdb) i r f
st0            3.46410161513775438635   (raw 0x4000ddb3d742c2655000)
st1            0        (raw 0x00000000000000000000)
st2            0        (raw 0x00000000000000000000)
st3            0        (raw 0x00000000000000000000)
st4            0        (raw 0x00000000000000000000)
st5            0        (raw 0x00000000000000000000)
st6            0        (raw 0x00000000000000000000)
st7            0        (raw 0x00000000000000000000)
fctrl          0x27f    639
fstat          0x3820   14368
ftag           0x3fff   16383
fiseg          0x33     51
fioff          0x4005a9 4195753
foseg          0x2b     43
fooff          0x601038 6295608
fop            0x0      0
(gdb) p *(double*)result
$1 = 0
(gdb) next
61              print
(gdb) p *(double*)result
$2 = 0
(gdb)
```

Comment: To print a double you need to pass it in `xmm0` **and** you need to set `al` to `1`. That said, it should be visible in the debugger, post log of what you did.

Comment: @Jester Printing is not the problem. There is nothing at result address after fstp instruction even though st0 has correct root in it before the instruction is executed.

Comment: Works fine here. Post log of what you did. I did `p *(double*)0x60104c` (that's the address in my case).

Comment: Did you do `p (double)result`?  `p &result` shows a stack address, which is weird.  `p result` complains about it having no type info.  So clearly there's a `result` symbol from somewhere, but its debug doesn't have the address of your BSS static storage.

Comment: @Jester I added my debug from terminal to the question. Does it matter if I'm using Linux subsystem for Windows? It worked fine till now.

Comment: @Nebeski The type of `result` is `double`, not `double *`.  That's why the debugger prints wrong data.

Comment: I'm using Arch Linux, but that shouldn't matter.  My previous comment is the answer: GDB has the wrong address for `result`.  I don't know why.  There's no problem with `fstp`, it's just with `result`.

Comment: @fuz I also used "x/g &result" and it still prints zero. And "result" is an address not a value in assembly.

Comment: Probably broken debug info. Disassemble the instruction to get the correct address.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think when you write p (double)result, you try to print a pointer 'result' as a double.

Comment: `result` isn't a pointer.  There are no pointer values stored anywhere in memory in your program, just static non-pointer data.  (Labels aren't pointers; they're not stored anywhere and you can't modify them).  If those 8 bytes did hold pointer data like `0x000000000060104c`, that bit-pattern as a `double` represents a very small denormal, so yeah it might print as `0.0` instead of `x.yE-1024`, but that's not what's happening here.  `p &result` tells us for sure that the debug info is broken, exactly like @Jester said (and like I said earlier).

Comment: Anyway, that's why `p *(double*)&result` prints zero as well, while `p *(double*)0x60104c` prints `1.732` after the `fstp` instruction runs.

Comment: I changed 'result' to 'rez' and now it works. I guess there was some other result in the program?

Comment: Yes, probably.  There's a `buf` somewhere in glibc, too, which causes the same problem for a common symbol name.  Oh actually, that `0x7ffff7dd4980` address for `result` is in glibc, not the stack.  They both start with `0x7fff...`, but the stack is closer to the top of the low 48 bits.  Anyway, `nm fsqrt` and `readelf -a` do show the BSS symbol address in your binary, but that's before dynamic linking happens.  Maybe if you used `global result` to export the symbol name, it would be the one that "wins" in GDB.

Comment: Yup, I checked and adding a `global result` line makes `p (double)result` work and print 1.73....  (As I though, when GDB needs you to tell it a type, casting the value itself selects the interpretation, not converting an integer to double or something.)

Comment: BTW, there's little point in saving/restoring RDI and a couple other regs around `printf` if you aren't going to save/restore *all* the call-clobbered registers.  Get used to call-clobbered registers being normal.  (Use a debugger, not debug-print macros.  It usually works well, except in cases like this with symbol name clashes.)